# c# dynamically removing selected labels from form

Tags: c#, controls, label

First of all. I have dynamically added labels. I want dynamically remove this labels after button_Click but I have a lot of labels on MainForm and I want remove only labels that calls **labelWorker**.
I tried something like this (example):

```
List<Control> controlsToRemove = new List<Control>();

foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is Label)
    {
        controlsToRemove.Add(ctrl);
    }
}

foreach (Control ctrl in controlsToRemove)
{
    this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
}
```

But this is for removing all Labels in WinForm. How to remove only:

```
Label labelWorker = new Label();
```

Before I'll create them again (without repetitions/overlaps).

Comment: you are missing the Name of the Label.. once you assign that name or ID it should work

Comment: I wrote this below but I'll write again here: When I'm using this code, only first created label is removing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give a name to your label

```
Label labelWorker = new Label();
labelWorker.Name = "labelWorker";
```

Then you can easily access it via it's name and remove

```
var labelToRemove = this.Controls["labelWorker"];
this.Controls.Remove(labelToRemove);
```

Ofcourse, you can apply this more than one label.Just make sure they have something incommon (like a prefix in the name), so you can distinguish them.

Comment: When I'm using this code, only first created label is removing.

Comment: `foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(x => x.Name == "labelWorker"))
{
    this.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
}`

Answer (score 2):

When you create labelWorker give it a Tag value to identify them. Then:

```
if (ctrl is Label && ((Label)ctrl).Tag.ToString() == "somevalue") controlsToRemove.Add(ctrl);
```

Comment: I'm trying to add this code somehow but this is to dificulty for me :( If you can write more code it would be great. Edit: ok, I get it now

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks.Just out of curiosity, I have Warning: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string', what does it mean?

Comment: @Kafus. The tag property is an object cast to a string to make it happy

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamicLabels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().Where(c => c.Tag != null && c.Tag.ToString() == "Dynamic").ToList();
foreach(var lbl in dynamicLabels)
    this.Controls.Remove(lbl);
```